# iOS-why my custom tableviewcell can't show label's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm just using code but not xib.
here's the code 
tableviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createData];
- (void)createData
{
    Model *user = [[Model alloc]init];
    [user setName:@"a"];
    [user setWeibo:@"a"];

    Model *user2 = [[Model alloc]init];
    [user2 setName:@"b"];
    [user2 setWeibo:@"b"];

    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:user,user2, nil];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Model *userData = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.name setText:userData.name];
    return cell;
}
```

cell.name is label.but it cannot show anything
please tell me how to let the custom tableviewcell's label to show something

I'm using UITableViewController so I guess i don't have to set tableviewdelegate and tableviewdatasorce.

and here's the tableviewcell's detail:

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    self.name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 15, 75, 30)];
    [self addSubview:self.name];

    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your `TableViewCell` class and its label.

Comment: Did you set the data Source? But like @rmaddy wrote, more details please.

Comment: Are you using Xib or using only code for UITableView

Comment: UITableView has great flexibility forcustomization.Usually you don't need subclass version of UITableView.